# Add new customers and print in opposite order?

Tags: java

I have a small task where I got a finished code which add 4 customer. My task is to "Reverse" this, which means print it in opposite order. I am not sure if I need to use while, for each loop or what?

Here is my code:

Customers.java:

```
//package com.itminds;

public class Customers {
    private String person;
    private Customers next;
    public Customers(Customers next, String person) {
        this.next = next;
        this.person = person;
    }

    public Customers getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public String getPerson() {
        return person;
    }

    public Customers previous(String person) {
        return new Customers(this, person);
    }

    public static Customers Create(String person) {
        return new Customers(null, person);
    }
}
```

Finder.java:

```
//package com.itminds;
import java.util.*;

public class Finder implements IFinder {
    public String fromRight(Customers customers, int numberFromRight) {
        while(customers != null){
                // MY FUNCTION:
                // print out: Petter, Ole, Hans, Kim
        }
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

IFinder.java:

```
//package com.itminds;

public interface IFinder {
    String fromRight(Customers customers, int numberFromRight);
}
```

Program.java:

```
//package com.itminds;

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Customers curr = Customers
                .Create("Kim")
                .previous("Hans")
                .previous("Ole")
                .previous("Peter");

        while (curr != null) {
            System.out.println(curr.getPerson());
            curr = curr.getNext();
        }
    }
}
```

How should I do this?

Comment: someone is trying to get us to do his homework...

Comment: Hint: This task is about bidirectional lists. You've got "pointers" to previous and next - whatever was implemented for "next" has to be implemented for "previous"